# How to read GraphQL HTTP response headers using Apollo on Android?

Tags: android, apollo

With code along the lines of the following, how can I access the HTTP response headers? I cannot find an API in Apollo that lets me access the HTTP response.

```
    fun getUser(result: AuthenticatedResult<Boolean>): Disposable {
    val query = FetchUserQuery.builder().build()
    val call = ApolloManager.client.query(query).httpCachePolicy(HttpCachePolicy.NETWORK_ONLY)

    val disposable = object : DisposableSingleObserver<Response<FetchUserQuery.Data>>() {

        override fun onSuccess(data: Response<FetchUserQuery.Data>) {
            if (!data.hasErrors()) {
                persistUser(data)
                result.success(true)
            } else {
                result.authenticationFailed()
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            ...
        }
    }

    Rx2Apollo.from(call)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .singleOrError()
            .subscribe(disposable)
    return disposable
}
```

Comment: Hey Ollie, aren't you receiving the headers in the data object in onSuccess method? Assuming you are using OkHttp for network call, there should be a headers field in response data object.

Comment: I've looked through the methods and properties in the data object (Response<FetchUserQuery.Data>) and cannot find the HTTP response or headers. There's no headers field on the data object. Apollo is using OkHttp.

Comment: I see no way to access the OkHttp Response, from the Apollo Response.